# What are the correct settings to create a text box on A5 pdf file

Tags: perl, pdf

I am trying to create a pdf file in perl using PDF::Create. I can't get the text at the correct position of the page.

It's an existing perl application which runs in Windows. It writes subscription cards to a text file and I want to convert that text file to a pdf file. I've tried various settings, but I can't get the text on the correct position.
I've created a pdf online from the text file and using Soda PDF online I got the coordinates of the text box, but I can't get them in my application.

```perl
my $kaart=read_text("kaart$myuserid.txt");
    my $pdf = PDF::Create->new(
        'filename' => "kaart$myuserid.pdf",
        "Author" => "Wattem",
        "Title" => "Kaart deelnemer ".$record->{deelnr},
        "CreationDate"=> [ localtime ]
    );
    my $root=$pdf->new_page("MediaBox"=>$pdf->get_page_size('A5'));
    my $page=$root->new_page;
    my $font=$pdf->font('BaseFont' => 'Times-Roman');
    my $toc = $pdf->new_outline('Title' => "Kaart deelnemer ".$record->{deelnr}, 'Destination' => $page);
    $page->block_text({
        page => $page,
        font => $font,
        text => $kaart,
        font_size => 10,
        text_color => [0,0,0],
        line_width => 400,
        start_y => 776,
        end_y => 327,
        'x' => 25,
        'y' => 10
    });
    $pdf->close;
```

I expect the text box to have the same size and position as I got with the online PDF converter and Soda PDF.
This is the information Soda PDF gave me for the text block:
X Position: 25.5
Y Position: 776.3921
Rotation: 0
Width: 293.7041
Height: 449.2844

Comment: Please provide a screen shot of the expected output also include the corresponding input text `$kaart`.

Comment: Or provide a download link to the PDF you created online

Comment: Here is an example of how the text file looks that is used to create the pdf: [link](https://bitbucket.org/mbch331/z4dperl/raw/ec2a53f19672cb7f4d1e73e148744fa90dc5769b/kaartz4d01.txt)

Comment: Thanks, could you also provide a link to the generated PDF?